# Getting images from the gallery shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog which sits alongside my website, both use the same database and I am currently accessing the database to pull in the latest blog articles in to my website. However, the blog is using the gallery shortcode so when I pull the post in to my page the script is displaying with my article content.

```
[gallery columns="1" link="file" ids="195,197"]
```

Is there any way I can use this to get the image paths from the db? I have checked and the IDs which it uses are no where to be found in the database, unless I am missing something?

Comment: It sounds as if your website and your blog are two separate entities. Just for clarification, your website is NOT using the Wordpress framework? Just sharing the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but posting answer in case someone else has the same problem.

My understanding of the issue is that you have (post) id's such as 195 and 197. Your external web application on the same database wants to retrieve file name references to these images.

The following query will provide you with the data you need:

`SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (195,197) AND meta_key = '_wp_attached_file';`

Example output:

```
+---------+----------------------+
| post_id | meta_value           |
+---------+----------------------+
|     195 | 2013/12/MK233212.jpg |
|     197 | 2013/12/MK233286.jpg |
+---------+----------------------+
```

The files are in a normal WordPress configuration found under `wp-content/uploads` directory.